# Codeigniter session store data does't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I made 2-3 project with codeigniter and ci session and work fine. Now I have to do a school project until Mondey with codeigniter and surprise.Session for login does't work even if i do same like in other projects. Here is my code.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('login_model');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }
    public function checkUserData()
    {
        //Parsarea datelor transmise de jquery(ajax)
        $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');   
        $data['password'] = $this->input->post('password');

        if($this->login_model->checkUserData($data) == "1")
        {
            //Sa nu uitam sa creem sesiunea si il redirectionam corespunzator
            $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                    'email' => $data['email'],
                    'password' => $data['password'],
                    'status' => TRUE
                ));
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is page where i redirect user.

```
class Newad extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    private $_email;
    public function index(){
        die($this->session->userdata('email'));
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        //header('Location: ' . base_url().$this->lang->lang()."/admin");
    }

}
```

I autoload session and I set encryption key. After login i see a blank page.
Thank you.